# Вывод строки в QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qmainwindow, qcursor

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Нужно сделать вывод координат курсора в углу оконного приложения.

```
    ...

    self.label = QLabel('Координаты курсора: x=0, y=0', self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
    
    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_cursor_position)
    self.timer.start(100)  # Обновление каждые 100 мс

def update_cursor_position(self):
    cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
    self.label.setText(f'Координаты курсора: x={cursor_pos.x()}, y={cursor_pos.y()}')

    ...
```

Но дело в том, что метод `setText` в данном случае вообще ничего не выводит в окне?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не предоставили минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и это не есть хорошо.

Я дополнил ваш пример и он работает как написано.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
  
        self.label = QLabel('Координаты курсора: x=0, y=0') 
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop) 
        
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_cursor_position)
        self.timer.start(100)         # Обновление каждые 100 мс

    def update_cursor_position(self):
        cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
        #print(f'{cursor_pos}') 
        
        self.label.setText('Координаты курсора: '\
            f'<span style="color: #D93333;">x={cursor_pos.x()}, y={cursor_pos.y()}<\span>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
  w = MainWindow()
  w.resize(500, 400)
  w.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: извините за возможно не корректный вопрос, но в какую часть кода основного файла надо это вставить, чтобы был вывод в окне приложения?

Comment: @ванякузнецов , sorry, я не понимаю о какой части кода основного файла вы спрашиваете. Опубликуйте ваш код или  предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и  тогда возможно будет понятнее, что и куда вам надо это вставить, хотя в моем примере все вставлено куда надо. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: а подскажите пожалуйста, сюда файл с кодом можно как-то загрузить, или только текстом вставлять? просто там на 2500 строк код

Comment: @ванякузнецов я не считал сколько строк кода можно опубликовать. Пример вы публикуете обычным текстом. Обычно публикуют минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который показывает проблему, а не весь проект. Вы можете опубликовать свой проект на github и в теле вопросы привести ссылку на него. Но лучше всего научиться составлять минимально-воспроизводимый пример, т.к. не каждый желающий вам помочь, захочет смотреть ваш полный проект.